# OpenAI Whisper API: "Invalid file format" on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, openai-api, openai-whisper

I am trying to do transcription on the voice of the user which is sent from the client as webm bytes with opus codecs. When running locally I have no issues in saving the bytes and reading them as file to use in the API.
When running the same code on Lambda I get this error:

> openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': "Invalid file format. Supported formats: ['flac', 'm4a', 'mp3', 'mp4', 'mpeg', 'mpga', 'oga', 'ogg', 'wav', 'webm']", 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}}.

This is my code:

```
@api_bp.post("/audio")
def transcribeRoute():
    audio_file = request.files.get('audio', None)

    if audio_file:
        print(audio_file) # <FileStorage: 'blob' ('audio/webm;codecs=opus')>


        old_work_dir = os.getcwd()

        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmp_dir:
            os.chdir(tmp_dir)

            try:
                input_file_path = 'recording.webm'
                audio_file.save(input_file_path)

                audio_file = open(input_file_path, "rb")
                print(audio_file) # <_io.BufferedReader name='recording.webm'>

                transcript = client.audio.transcriptions.create(model="whisper-1",file=audio_file).text

            finally:
                os.remove(input_file_path)
                os.chdir(old_work_dir)

        print(f"Transcribed audio: {transcript}")
        return {"transcription": transcript}, 200

    print("No audio file found")
    return {"transcription": "error"}, 400
```

My first thought was that this is an issue with Lambda's temporary storage. However it seems that /tmp works and has 500mb of storage. Printing the file also confirms that it is saved and can be read.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit 1**
I now just use the raw bytes instead of saving it first to remove the possibility of it being an error in the filesystem.

```
@api_bp.post("/audio")
def transcribeRoute():
    audio_file = request.files.get('audio', None)

    if audio_file:
        print(audio_file) # <FileStorage: 'blob' ('audio/webm;codecs=opus')>

        buffer = BytesIO(audio_file.read())
        buffer.name = "test.webm"

        transcript = client.audio.transcriptions.create(model="whisper-1", file=buffer).text

        print(f"Transcribed audio: {transcript}")
        return {"transcription": transcript}, 200

    print("No audio file found")
    return {"transcription": "error"}, 400
```

I am still investigating [this thread](https://community.openai.com/t/whisper-api-cannot-read-files-correctly/93420/29), which made me think, that maybe this is something with a dependency on the host machine. To find out I rehosted the code to Lambda with lambda Docker image which threw the same error. Running the program locally in the official python:3.9 image works with no problems. When deploying this to lambda again it starts throwing errors once again.

My current theory is that the binary-data somehow gets corrupted when sending it over the API-Gateway, since when I try to read that data and transform it into another format it starts breaking (only on Lambda, local is no problem). This is what I get:
Output from ffmpeg/avlib:

```
2023-12-06T15:14:21.776+01:00   ffmpeg version 5.1.4-0+deb12u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 12 (Debian 12.2.0-14)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb12u1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --disable-sndio --enable-libjxl --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libplacebo --enable-librav1e --enable-shared

libavutil 57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
libavcodec 59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
libavformat 59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
ibavdevice 59. 7.100 / 59. 7.100
libavfilter 8. 44.100 / 8. 44.100
libswscale 6. 7.100 / 6. 7.100
libswresample 4. 7.100 / 4. 7.100
libpostproc 56. 6.100 / 56. 6.100
[matroska,webm @ 0x55802d5b9e00] Element at 0x44 ending at 0x83 exceeds containing master element ending at 0x74
[matroska,webm @ 0x55802d5b9e00] EBML header parsing failed
pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: `Supported formats: ['flac', 'm4a', 'mp3', 'mp4', 'mpeg', 'mpga', 'oga', 'ogg', 'wav', 'webm']` - I don't see `opus` on list. Maybe you need different format. Or maybe it needs to install `C/C++` library for `opus`.

Comment: Opus is just a codecs, the file itself is a webm file, which also works like this locally. Maybe it needs a special library for that to read and write codecs, but wouldn't that normally throw an error if a dependency is missing?

Comment: as I said it may need to install `C/C++` library for `opus`. Without this library it doesn't have to raise error when you install it but when you try to use wrong format. Wihtout this library it is still useful if you only use other formats - ie. `webm + mp3` or `webm + wav` or `webm + flac`

Comment: There is an apt package called opus-tools, do you mean just download it or is there any specific code I have to add in order to format it?

Comment: I don't use `AWS` so I can only guess. On my local Linux Mint using `apt search opus` I see also `libopus0` and this can be codec `opus`. I hope `OpenAI` will check all codecs on start and it will see `libopus0` - but maybe it may need to recompile `OpenAI` or install `OpenAI` and it will add `opus` to supported formats. But you will have to test it on your own because I don't have `AWS` to test it.

Comment: I downloaded the dependencies and run them locally with a Docker image which worked fine once again. Deploying the same Docker image now starts throwing errors again (see newest edit). I think the API-Gateway may be corrupting my data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trying and researching the problem was a mix of 2 issues:
a) In order for the Whisper API to work, the buffer with the audio-bytes has to have a name (which happens automatically when you write and read it to the file, just make sure you have the right extension).
b) The AWS API-Gateway doesn't support binary data in requests by default, and you have to manually allow it. F.e. if you are using Serverless Framework for deployment add this:

```
provider:
  apiGateway:
    binaryMediaTypes:
      - '*/*'
```