OpenAI API return 400 Error: cannot transcribe ogg file
I want to create async func for transcribing telegram voices (.ogg files), but when i try send request to OpenAI API i recive error:

Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': "Unrecognized file format.
Supported formats: ['flac', 'm4a', 'mp3', 'mp4', 'mpeg', 'mpga',
'oga', 'ogg', 'wav', 'webm']", 'type': 'invalid_request_error',
'param': None, 'code': None}}

Here is code of my functions:
async def transcribe_voice_message(file_path):
    """OpenAI Speech To Text request"""
    client = AsyncOpenAI(api_key=openai_api_key)
    try:
        async with aiofiles.open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            file_content = await f.read()
            transcription = await client.audio.transcriptions.create(
            model="whisper-1", file=file_content
            )
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(
            f"Open API error: {e}"
        )
    return transcription.text


I tried different ways to solve this problem, change type files to .mp3, change object types to IO[bytes] or bytes, but the error remains the same.

Solved by this message: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77616053/12834417

In order for the Whisper API to work, the buffer with the audio-bytes has to have a name

New code:
async def transcribe_voice_message(file_path):
    """OpenAI Speech To Text request"""
    client = AsyncOpenAI(api_key=openai_api_key)
    try:
        async with aiofiles.open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            file_content = await f.read()
            buffer = io.BytesIO(file_content)
            buffer.name = os.path.basename(file_path)

            transcription = await client.audio.transcriptions.create(
            model="whisper-1", file=buffer
            )
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(
            f"Open API error: {e}"
        )
    return transcription.text


The main problem here is that openai services can't understand which file extension you are using. You should specify it explicitly.
We want to get voice from telegram. If you are using aiogram, you can directly save voice file into BytesIO, without saving it into your system.
from io import BytesIO

@router.message(F.voice) 
async def transcript_voice(message: Message):
    # prepare file to download from telegram database
    file = await message.bot.get_file(file_id=message.voice.file_id)

    # create buffer where we will store voice file
    buffer = BytesIO()

    # use aiogram's built-in function to download voice file
    await message.bot.download_file(file_path=file.file_path, destination=buffer)

    # get extension of file (if the file extension is not .ogg, you may find this useful in transcribing audio files, e.g. .mp3)
    file_extension = file.file_path.split('.')[1]

    # (!) set file name and file extension
    buffer.name = f"file.{file_extension}"
    buffer.seek(0)

    # send request to Whisper-1; better wrap it into try-except
    response = await client.audio.transcriptions.create(
        model='whisper-1',
        file=buffer
    )
    await message.answer(response.text)

However, if you prefer to save file in system, then you may refer to Антон Кокорин's answer

There are two codecs that encode in .ogg format: opus and vorbis . Most probably OpenAI support only one of this codecs, not both of them. I would suggest to check your audio file format by running ffprobe on it:
ffprobe your_file.ogg

